# Why can't I acces my image's source using Screenmanager and ObjectProperty?

Tags: python, properties, kivy, kivy-language

I'd like to access my image's source by pointing to its ID.
When I try it this way without using ScreenManager it works fine but using ScreenManager and gives the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'source'

So do you have any idea how to access my image using ScreenManager?

Python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class MainWindow(Screen):

    img1 = ObjectProperty(None)

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    self.print_image()

def print_image(self):
    print(self.img1)


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


Gui = Builder.load_file("my.kv")


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Gui


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

kv code:

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    img1: img1

    Button:
        id: b1
        text: "Submit"

    Image:
        id: img1
        source: "IMG_8681.jpg"


<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"

    Button:
        text: "Go Back"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "main"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `Image` as you described, but a `print` statement in a class, outside any method, is executed when the class is loaded and even before the `kv` file is loaded.

You can access the `Image` like this:

```
print(Gui.get_screen('main').img1)
```

or within a method in the `MainWindow` class, you can use:

```
print(self.img1)
```

But you must wait till the `App` is started

Comment: As I said in my answer: "you must wait till the App is started". The `__init__()` method of `MainWindow` is executed before the `App` is started.